# name of images from folder not printed on screen in php

Tags: php, json

I have an html file and i have done the code for `printing the names of images from a folder` in PHP , but it is not printing the values to screen.  if i echo any other thing it is printed on screen.

i have the set the server using xampp.

how to correct this, i make the names of images from that folder printed on screen?

do i need to do anything extra

im a newbie in php. how can i achieve this?

```js
<?php

function findImagesInFolder()
{
    $folder = $_GET['C:\xampp\htdocs\firstsite'];
    $images = glob($folder . '/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

    echo json_encode($images);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have misused the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable.

I thing you want to just use the string value, ie.:

```
$folder = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\firstsite';
```

And note, the [exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) terminates whole script after printing the json_encoded string.

So, to make the function reusable change it to get the path as a parameter `$folder`:

```
<?php

function findImagesInFolder($folder, $filter = '*.*')
{
    // note, here we expect the path does not trail with backslash
    $images = glob($folder . '\\' . $filter, GLOB_BRACE);
    return json_encode($images);
}

// call the function with actual path to scan:
$path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\firstsite';
$filter = '{*.png,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif}';
echo findImagesInFolder($path, $filter);
?>
```

Note: output as `[]` means empty array encoded to JSON.

---

Comment: changed the code and called the function with actual path to scan and it shows [] opening and closing brace

Comment: I have updated the code. Note the backslash in glob() function.

Comment: i have seen te update and used the glob the udated backslash,  get [] opening and closing bractet as output

Comment: $images = glob($folder . '\{*.png,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
 used this glob parameter and still getting [] openig,closing bracket as output

Comment: ok,, so the problem was with the backslash - has to be escaped, of course :D And I have change the function to use second, optional param for the filter.

Comment: if i echo something like`hello` i get `hello[]`

Comment: Is the target folder accessible? Try `echo findImagesInFolder('.');`
And Always debug your scripts with enabled [PHP Error Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)!

Comment: it could be easier if you put the last backslash in the path... without backslashing it in the globe argument

Comment: @ino wheni echo findImagesInfolder('.') it is giving me` [][".\\23.jpg",".\\24.jpg",".\\25.jpg",".\\Untitled-1.php"]`